# Multiple similar functions mapped to one hotkey?

Tags: scripting

First time posting to these forums. I am in the process of trying to learn Blender having come from a Max, then Maya centric workflow. I was wondering how difficult it would be to map a series of similar functions to a single key that can then cycle through them?

I tend to want to have as few hotkeys to remember as possible and have found that this was a good way to go about it. As an example, in Maya, I have one hotkey that cycles through transform modes, and another that handles axis constraints. In theory, I could also create one that cycles through subobject modes.

Thanks.

Comment: I've never used Maya or Max so I don't exactly understand what you need. Blender has context  menus, accessible pressing the right mouse button, the meny change according to the editor and tools selected. And there is also a Dynamic context menu addon: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/interface/context_menu.html?highlight=context%20menu

Answer (score 1):

Blender has a quick favorites menu, hotkey = q. To add operations to the quick favorites menu, simply right click on the operation and choose add to quick favorites.

For example, let's say I want the add mesh operation to be in my quick favorites menu:[image]

Now when I hit q this is what I see.
[image]